# show that$ X$ is uncountable if $(X,d)$ is connected

Tags: general-topology

if $(X,d)$ is a connected metric space and there exist non-constant real-valued continuous function $f$ in $X$, show that $X$ is uncountable

Comment: The hypothesis that there is a non-constant real-valued continuous function on $X$ ensures that $X$ has at least two points.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $f(X)$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R$.  But you don't have to **assume** existence of $f$: if $X$ has more than one point, try $f(x) = d(x,x_0)$ where $x_0 \in X$.